# Can I configure the pool size of a specific Quarkus Vertx ConsumeEvent?

Tags: java, quarkus, vert.x

The parameter `quarkus.vertx.worker-pool-size` allows me to configure the "Thread size of the worker thread pool", according to the [quarkus guide - All configuration options](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config).

Is it possible to configure the pool size of a specific Quarkus ConsumeEvent like this:

```java
    @io.quarkus.vertx.ConsumeEvent(value = "my-consume-event", blocking = true)
    public void start(String value) {
      // do the work
    }
```

I would like to set the number of threads that can process this `my-consume-event` without changing the global `quarkus.vertx.worker-pool-size`.

## SmallRye Reactive Messaging example of configurable thread pool

On the [SmallRye Reactive Messaging guide](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/smallrye-reactive-messaging/3.1/advanced/blocking.html) there's one example of what I want to do.

Here, I can use one Blocking annotation, define one name for it and configure the thread pool:

```java
@Outgoing("Y")
@Incoming("X")
@Blocking("my-custom-pool")
public String process(String s) {
  return s.toUpperCase();
}
```

> Specifying the concurrency for the above worker pool requires the following configuration property to be defined:

```
smallrye.messaging.worker.my-custom-pool.max-concurrency=3
```

In this example, I can configure the size of the thread pool that will process the messages from the `my-custom-pool`.

Thanks

## Edit to include try with `@io.smallrye.common.annotation.Blocking("my-custom-pool")`

I tried to set a value to the `@io.smallrye.common.annotation.Blocking("my-custom-pool")` annotation, but I receive the following error:

```
The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type Blocking
```

I'm using this dependency:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-vertx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I also created [this project on my GitHub account](https://github.com/felipewind/event-bus-test) to do this test.

#### Class that does the test

```java
package org.acme;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

import io.vertx.core.eventbus.EventBus;

@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(GreetingResource.class);

    @Inject
    EventBus eventBus;

    @GET
    public Response hello() {
        LOG.info("hello()");
        eventBus.send("my-consume-event", null);
        return Response
                .status(Response.Status.ACCEPTED)
                .build();
    }

    @io.quarkus.vertx.ConsumeEvent("my-consume-event")
    // @io.smallrye.common.annotation.Blocking("my-custom-pool")
    @io.smallrye.common.annotation.Blocking
    public void start(String value) {
        try {
            LOG.info("before the sleep");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            LOG.info("after the sleep");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I opened this issue https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/25259

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `@io.smallrye.common.annotation.Blocking` annotation:

```
@ConsumeEvent("my-consume-event")
@Blocking("my-custom-pool")
public void start(String value) {
  // do the work
}
```

And configure your pool size in `application.properties`:

```
smallrye.messaging.worker.my-custom-pool.max-concurrency=3
```

**EDIT**

Actually, the `@io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.annotations.Blocking` is not supported on methods annotated with `@ConsumeEvent`.

Also, according to [ConsumeEvent with Blocking Threading on wrong ExecutorService #19911](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/19911), it seems events are executed on the default Quarkus executor.

Comment: I updated my question to include this test. When I try to put `@io.smallrye.common.annotation.Blocking("my-custom-pool")`, I receive the error `The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type Blocking`.

Comment: In you properties file, change `quarkus.vertx.worker-pool-size=2` to `smallrye.messaging.worker.my-custom-pool.max-concurrency=3`

Comment: I'm having a compilation problem, when I put @io.smallrye.common.annotation.Blocking("my-custom-pool"), I receive the error The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type Blocking. You can see this in my test project - https://github.com/felipewind/event-bus-test. It's not possible to passa a value to the io.smallrye.common.annotation.Blocking annotation.

Comment: Sorry, I made a confusion, it seems the `@io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.annotations.Blocking` annotation is not supported on such methods. I will update my reply.

Comment: Thanks for helping. According the [Quarkus Event Bus Guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-event-bus#consuming-events), you can use the `@io.smallrye.common.annotation.Blocking`. But this annotation doesn't allow to pass a value like `@io.smallrye.common.annotation.Blocking("my-custom-pool")`. And you're right, the `@io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.annotations.Blocking` can't be used with @ConsumeEvent.